# Styles in the react application loading only after page refresh

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, react-router

I am facing an issue with styles in my react application i.e. I have 2 components Home and Items. When the route happens form Home->Items the styles are not properly loaded. If I refresh  the Items page then the styles get loaded. Also if I navigate directly to domainname.com/home/items the styles get loaded.

Comment: Please add relevant code snippets to your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking - please review it and edit your question.

Comment: @AndrewL64 i cannot share the code because it is  a large application, In the question i have given a simple explanation so the issue i am facing could be explained.

Comment: It is very hard to say like that. How are you loading your style? do you use a library? is it inline? do you use normal css?..... so many questions open.... can you provide a mini example on codesandbox.com or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

if you use `next.js` or setup `code-splitting` somehow (for `SSR` propose) ,this will happen. that's because of dynamic import and code-splitting.

if you use `next.js` this problem happens only in the development environment. when you build your app (`npm build`) and then run your app (`npm start`) this problem will be solved.

otherwise, if you don't use next.js, you have to consider your code-splitting method.  ([react code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html))